# Western Europe tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I believe the [western-europe](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/western-europe) tag to be unnecessary. Virtually all of Western Europe is covered by the EU, and outside of that employment law is different enough that separate questions should usually be asked.

Comment: sounds a bit meta-taggish... what about "eastern europe"? should we do it also? anyways no asker has created it so far so it would seem nobody has needed it so far...

Comment: "Western Europe" is not a juristiction. It's not even a culture. It's pointless. People should post their actual country.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)? There are [no more questions with that tag](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/western-europe); for posterity, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220609021451/https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/western-europe) are a couple of questions which had it earlier this year.

Comment: This is due to OP running around the site and pre-emptively removing the tag from all questions that had it